# Strapi custom endpoint is unavailable, returns not found

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have created a custom controller with the following configurations:

This is running on local docker containers. I have added other custom endpoints in similar manner but just recently when i added another endpoint, i got stuck with this issue.

The below endpoint is showing under on the Roles & Permissions in the Strapi dashboard

Controller.js

```
module.exports = {
  async stock(ctx) {
    console.log("stocks called ==")
    return { message: "success" }
   }
};
```

Routes.json

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/materials/stock",
  "handler": "material.stock",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```

Permission has been added for the authenticated user, but still when calling this endpoint http://localhost:80/materials/stock it returns with `{ "statusCode": 404, "error": "Not Found", "message": "Not Found" }`

`Solution:`

Change the method to `POST`. Using the method as `GET` doesn't seems to be working. Some kind of bug with Strapi or probably something wrong with my configuration.

Comment: your handler is material.stock without the 's', is this typo, should it be ```materials.stock```?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial nope. it's correct. i am using the default find,count,create, with the same handler  like `material.find`

Comment: Actually now,  if i add any custom endpoint on any of the controllers it just returns `not found`

Comment: found the bug. the method should be `POST`, making the method `GET` doesn't seems to work